# How do I calculate accuracy(and other metrics) in multi-label edge segmentation in PyTorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, edge-detection

I am working on edge segmentation with [CASENet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.09759). Their idea is that a pixel can belong to more than one class at the same time. I am using the pytorch implementation of CASENet provided by [DFF](https://github.com/Lavender105/DFF)  on my custom dataset consisting of 3 classes.

I am trying to calculate the accuracy per class in this setting since I cannot monitor the model's performance only based on the loss.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
def training(self, epoch):
    self.model.train()
    tbar = tqdm(self.trainloader)
    # tbar = self.trainloader
    train_loss = 0.
    train_loss_all = 0.

    acc_class0 = 0.
    acc_class1 = 0.
    acc_class2 = 0.
    acc_class0_all = 0.
    acc_class1_all = 0.
    acc_class2_all = 0.
    
    correct_class0 = 0.
    correct_class1 = 0.
    correct_class2 = 0.
    correct_class0_all = 0.
    correct_class1_all = 0.
    correct_class2_all = 0.
    
    total = 0.
    total_all = 0.
    
    for i, (image, target) in enumerate(tbar):
        self.scheduler(self.optimizer, i, epoch)
        self.optimizer.zero_grad()
        if torch_ver == "0.3":
            image = Variable(image)
            target = Variable(target)

        image = image.cuda()
        target = target.cuda()

        outputs = self.model(image.float())

        loss = self.criterion(outputs, target)
        loss.backward()

        self.optimizer.step()

        train_loss += loss.item()
        train_loss_all += loss.item()

        total += target[0][1,:,:].nelement() * target.size(0)
        total_all += target[0][1,:,:].nelement() * target.size(0)

        correct_0, correct_1, correct_2 = self.get_accuracy_stats(outputs[1], target)
        correct_class0 += correct_0
        correct_class1 += correct_1
        correct_class2 += correct_2
        
        correct_class0_all += correct_0
        correct_class1_all += correct_1
        correct_class2_all += correct_2

        if i == 0 or (i+1) % 20 == 0:
            train_loss = train_loss / min(20, i + 1)
            acc_class0 = 100 * correct_class0 / total
            acc_class1 = 100 * correct_class1 / total
            acc_class2 = 100 * correct_class2 / total

            # self.logger.info('Epoch [%d], Batch [%d],\t train-loss: %.4f' % (
            #        epoch + 1, i + 1, train_loss))
            self.logger.info('Epoch [%d], Batch [%d],\t train-loss: %.4f,\t class1 acc: %.3f,\t class2 acc: %.3f,\t class3 acc: %.3f' % (
                epoch + 1, i + 1, train_loss, acc_class0, acc_class1, acc_class2))
            train_loss = 0.
            total = 0.
            correct_class0 = 0.
            correct_class1 = 0.
            correct_class2 = 0.

    acc_class0_all = 100 * correct_class0_all / total_all
    acc_class1_all = 100 * correct_class1_all / total_all
    acc_class2_all = 100 * correct_class2_all / total_all

    #self.logger.info('-> Epoch [%d], Train epoch loss: %.3f' % (
    #                epoch + 1, train_loss_all / (i + 1)))
    self.logger.info('-> Epoch [%d], Train epoch loss: %.3f,\t class1 epoch acc: %.3f,\t class2 epoch acc: %.3f,\t class3 epoch acc: %.3f' % (
                     epoch + 1, train_loss_all / (i + 1), acc_class0_all, acc_class1_all, acc_class2_all))

    if not self.args.no_val:
        # save checkpoint every 20 epoch
        filename = "checkpoint_%s.pth.tar"%(epoch+1)
        if epoch % 19 == 0 or epoch == args.epochs-1:
            utils.save_checkpoint({
                'epoch': epoch + 1,
                'state_dict': self.model.state_dict(),
                'optimizer': self.optimizer.state_dict(),
                }, self.args, filename)

    self.viz.line(win=self.loss_plot, name='train_loss', update='append', X=np.array([epoch+1]),
             Y=np.array([train_loss_all / (i + 1)]))

def get_accuracy_stats(self, predicted, targets):
    correct_class_outputs = [[] for x in range(predicted[0].size(0))]

    for i in range(targets.size(0)):
        predictions = predicted[i]
        target = targets[i]
        pad_mask = target[0, :, :]
        target = target[1:, :, :]
        target_nopad = torch.mul(target, pad_mask)
        predictions_nopad = torch.mul(predictions, pad_mask)

        for j in range(predictions_nopad.size(0)):
            class_pred = predictions_nopad[j]
            class_target = target_nopad[j]

            class_output = torch.sigmoid(class_pred)
            class_output = torch.round(class_output)
            correct_class_outputs[j].append((class_output == class_target).sum().item())

    return sum(correct_class_outputs[0]), sum(correct_class_outputs[1]), sum(correct_class_outputs[2])
```

Some background:

In the line:

```py
outputs = self.model(image.float())
```

my output logits is a tuple of the form:([6, 3, 512, 512], [6, 3, 512, 512]) -> The first tuple item is the side5 output of the model and the 2nd item is the model's fused layer output. 3 is the edge maps belonging to their respective classes, if I understand this correctly. I am only considering the 2nd tuple item for calculation of the accuracy as I am not interested in the side5 output.

My target is of the form: [6, 4, 512, 512] where `target[i][0,:,:]` is a padded mask which is excluded from the [loss calculation](https://github.com/Lavender105/DFF/blob/master/exps/losses/customize.py) and `target[i][1:,:,:]` is the actual target.

I would like to know if my code for accuracy calculation per class is correct and am I on the right path? Or is there an easier way to do this? I feel that I have missed out something as I get strange outputs for accuracy always outputting above 90% for all the batches.

Here is a sample output:

```
2022-02-23 16:52:39:
=>Epoches 0, learning rate = 0.0100
2022-02-23 16:52:42: Epoch [1], Batch [1],   train-loss: 0.8800,     class1 acc: 3.627,  class2 acc: 99.756,     class3 acc: 3.417

  1%|          | 19/1540 [00:18<19:35,  1.29it/s]2022-02-23 16:52:55: Epoch [1], Batch [20],     train-loss: 0.6791,     class1 acc: 80.341,     class2 acc: 99.837,     class3 acc: 60.657

  3%|▎         | 39/1540 [00:32<18:19,  1.37it/s]2022-02-23 16:53:10: Epoch [1], Batch [40],     train-loss: 0.4224,     class1 acc: 94.660,     class2 acc: 98.015,     class3 acc: 97.362

  4%|▍         | 59/1540 [00:47<17:41,  1.39it/s]2022-02-23 16:53:25: Epoch [1], Batch [60],     train-loss: 0.3861,     class1 acc: 94.057,     class2 acc: 97.624,     class3 acc: 95.716

  5%|▌         | 79/1540 [01:02<17:57,  1.36it/s]2022-02-23 16:53:40: Epoch [1], Batch [80],     train-loss: 0.3689,     class1 acc: 94.118,     class2 acc: 97.754,     class3 acc: 95.444

  6%|▋         | 99/1540 [01:16<17:08,  1.40it/s]2022-02-23 16:53:54: Epoch [1], Batch [100],    train-loss: 0.3326,     class1 acc: 92.769,     class2 acc: 98.245,     class3 acc: 94.348

  8%|▊         | 119/1540 [01:31<16:53,  1.40it/s]2022-02-23 16:54:08: Epoch [1], Batch [120],   train-loss: 0.3048,     class1 acc: 93.446,     class2 acc: 97.996,     class3 acc: 95.004

  9%|▉         | 139/1540 [01:45<16:42,  1.40it/s]2022-02-23 16:54:23: Epoch [1], Batch [140],   train-loss: 0.3570,     class1 acc: 93.433,     class2 acc: 98.012,     class3 acc: 94.916

 10%|█         | 159/1540 [01:59<16:27,  1.40it/s]2022-02-23 16:54:37: Epoch [1], Batch [160],   train-loss: 0.3236,     class1 acc: 92.567,     class2 acc: 98.614,     class3 acc: 94.335

 12%|█▏        | 179/1540 [02:14<17:10,  1.32it/s]2022-02-23 16:54:52: Epoch [1], Batch [180],   train-loss: 0.3651,     class1 acc: 92.132,     class2 acc: 97.685,     class3 acc: 93.697

 13%|█▎        | 199/1540 [02:30<17:42,  1.26it/s]2022-02-23 16:55:08: Epoch [1], Batch [200],   train-loss: 0.3106,     class1 acc: 93.269,     class2 acc: 98.169,     class3 acc: 94.849

 14%|█▍        | 219/1540 [02:46<17:33,  1.25it/s]2022-02-23 16:55:24: Epoch [1], Batch [220],   train-loss: 0.3878,     class1 acc: 91.229,     class2 acc: 97.875,     class3 acc: 93.294

 16%|█▌        | 239/1540 [03:02<17:49,  1.22it/s]2022-02-23 16:55:40: Epoch [1], Batch [240],   train-loss: 0.3361,     class1 acc: 93.295,     class2 acc: 98.609,     class3 acc: 94.954

 17%|█▋        | 259/1540 [03:18<16:29,  1.29it/s]2022-02-23 16:55:56: Epoch [1], Batch [260],   train-loss: 0.3350,     class1 acc: 94.269,     class2 acc: 98.122,     class3 acc: 95.307

 18%|█▊        | 279/1540 [03:33<15:11,  1.38it/s]2022-02-23 16:56:11: Epoch [1], Batch [280],   train-loss: 0.3167,     class1 acc: 93.818,     class2 acc: 98.189,     class3 acc: 94.971

 19%|█▉        | 299/1540 [03:49<17:16,  1.20it/s]2022-02-23 16:56:27: Epoch [1], Batch [300],   train-loss: 0.3230,     class1 acc: 91.987,     class2 acc: 98.382,     class3 acc: 93.885
```

Also, how would I go about calculating other metrics such as F1 (during training) as that would be a better indicator of the model's performance?